# Pull data from multidimension array if a string value is defined

Tags: php, arrays

I want to pull the string value of `[totalPrice]` , `[boardType]` , `[roomCategory]`  if the `[hotelCode]` value is known.

The array `print_r` is (there only one hotel,)

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
[processId] => H5-84752260 
[hotelCode] => GRSCDS 
[availabilityStatus] => InstantConfirmation 
[totalPrice] => 40 [totalTax] => 0 
[totalSalePrice] => 0 
[currency] => EUR 
[boardType] => Room and Breakfast (American Buffet Breakfast) 
[rooms] => Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
[roomCategory] => Twin Room 
[paxes] => Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
[paxType] => Adult 
[age] => 30 ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( 
[paxType] => Adult 
[age] => 30 ) ) 
[totalRoomRate] => 40 
[ratesPerNight] => Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
[date] => 2015-03-11 [amount] => 40 ) ) ) ) ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate array, check item with if condition and grab values you need. Like this:

```
<?php
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if ($item->hotelCode === 'YOUR_CODE') {
            // get your data here using $item->totalPrice, etc
            break;
        }
    }
```